# Using an external Saver with a Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying use a framework called ray (http://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to perform hyper parameter optimization of a tensorflow model which in implemented as a custom estimator. The model uses the tf.data datasets/iterators to feed the model.

To use model based optimization ray requires us to implement a class which can both checkpoint and restore the model. As far as I can tell this requires us use an external Saver instance to manage the checkpointing and restoring. The part I have not been able to make work is building an initializable iterator that I can reinitialize when restoring the model.

I am looking to understand the following:

1. Is there any guidance on using a Saver (or some other external from the estimator mechanism) to manage the checkpointing and restoring of a model?
2. I have not been able to create an initializable iterator within the input function which is fed to the estimator. It gives me an error that it's not in the same graph which I guess makes sense given that the graph of the main model has not yet been created. Is there a different way to create an initializable iterator for use with an estimator?

I am trying to keep the model as an estimator for all the obvious advantages that it offers and would prefer not to have to maintain two different versions of the model.